# What was the reason for the ubiquitous pigeon farms in Soviet cities?

Tags: soviet-union, animals

They were in just any district.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you narrow down a time frame when these first appeared?

Comment: @user2448131 I think they grew sharply after 1950s.

Comment: Tastes like chicken.

Answer (score 3):

[Pidgeon keeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_keeping) is a real thing, for sports (pidgeon races), just admiring them (as pets), for food, as messenger pidgeons...

Comment: The pigeon meat was not consumed in the USSR, and most of pigeons in those farms were totally common (not well-bred sorts).

Comment: @Anixx: My neighbour is keeping some as well, and *I* cannot tell them apart from the hundreds of wild pidgeons around the place either. He on the other hand can possibly make neither head nor tail of my various longbows...

Comment: And there were likely no pigeon races in the USSR.

Comment: @Anixx: Which still leaves using them as (cheap!) messengers, or just pets that are _very_ easy to keep (and replace...).

Comment: @Anixx - incorrect, there was pigeon racing in the USSR.  This was a peoples hobby to a huge extent.  Pigeon racing even predates the USSR.

Answer (score 3):

I can offer one other possible explanation besides [squab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squab). Manure.

According to this site on [Micro-livestock](http://www.appropedia.org/Micro-livestock:_Little-known_Small_Animals_with_a_Promising_Economic_Future_5):

> Pigeons are traditionally raised in dovecotes - "houses" that protect
>   the birds from the elements and from predators. This system allows
>   free-ranging flight and requires almost no human intervention.
>   Dovecotes are a good source of both squab and garden manure, and they
>   continue to be used, especially in Egypt

The buildings you show seem to match the [dovecote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovecote), specifically the 'urban' design. So if they weren't harvesting the pigeon, it may have been a convenient method of obtaining hard to get, free fertilizer in city areas for gardens.

Answer (score 3):

Pigeon keeping was widespread in Russia (and perhaps some other countries of future USSR) even before the Soviet Union. The birds were kept as purely decorative pets, with no practical use whatsoever. They were not, under normal circumstances, eaten (except at times of famine), not used as messenger birds (there were messenger pigeons, but they were raised at more specialized facilities). Mostly, wealthy enough villagers would spend money on buying exotic pigeons to keep in their pigeon houses. "Exotic" not only in terms of appearance but also in terms of their flying pattern. There were some techniques to control their flight from the ground, to a degree - like waving flags or something. Dedicated pigeon keepers would brag for hours who has better pigeons and how they fly, etc. To my knowledge, the tradition declined later in the Soviet Union, but was (or *is*) still present.